# How to call javaScript function in php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to call a javaScript function in a php Div. I have tried somethings, but they do not work.
Here are the code lines.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    //Set the image here. (I would like to set the image here. )
    //That is what I have tried, but it does not work.
    <?php $img_name = echo  $row['img_name']; ?> //e.g. $img_name = cat.jpg; ?>
    //Call the  img() function to set the image
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'img('.$img_name.');', '</script>';
</div>
```

Here is the js function

```
<script>
function img(img_src){
    //Create div
    var m_div = document.createElement('Div');
    m_div.style.background = "green";
    m_div.id = "id_div";

    //Create img
    var img_input = document.createElement('img');
    img_input.id = "id_img"; 
    img_input.src = "images/" + img_src; // e.g. img_src = cat.jpg;
    img_input.height = "380";
    img_input.width = "290";

    //Append img to div
    document.getElementById("m_div").appendChild("img_input");
}
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call javascript from PHP. You have to use PHP to produce HTML that in-turn can call the javascript function. Print out the image file name from the PHP variable -> into the HTML -> as a parameter value into the javascript function.

```
    $img_name = 'showMe.jpg';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">img("'.$img_name.'")</script>';
```

Comment: Injecting arbitrary data into script (or even HTML) isn't a great idea.  At least use `json_encode()` to be compatible.

Comment: Thank you @user_pt. I have considered your opinion and I have created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61569289/how-to-create-and-display-image-in-php Please have a look there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call js from PHP. PHP is a backend language that means run before the javascript loaded, javascript is a frontend language that means is loaded after the browser loads the page.

However you can pass PHP to javascript but is not recommended. It is better to use [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to load the variable from the server. This is a link to read more information about [pass variables from PHP t to javascript](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-pass-variables-from-php-to-javascript.html).

example:

```
//Call the  img() function to set the image
<script type="text/javascript">
  var row = <?php echo  json_encode($row); ?>; //e.g. $img_name = cat.jpg; ?>
  (function(image) {
      img(image);
  })(row.img_name);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Fermin Perdomo. I have considered your opinion and I have created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61569289/how-to-create-and-display-image-in-php Please have a look there.