# How to create and display image in PHP

Tags: php, html, image, function

I would like to display an image using PHP. Here is what I have tried, but it does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<?php
$img_name = echo  $row['img_name']; //I get it from the database
img_block($img_name); //Display the image here.

//Function to display image
function img_block(img_src) {
    // e.g. img_src = cat.jpg;
    $img_input = "images/" . img_src;
    $set_img = '<img class="media-object-ph" src="'.$img_input.'" width="380" height="290" alt="...">';
    return $set_img;
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try changing `$img_input` to `$img_input = "./images/ ... "`

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is this problem related to [tag:function]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment... You have a number of errors:

```
$img_name = echo  $row['img_name'];
```

should be:

```
$img_name = $row['img_name'];
```

You are calling your function but not doing anything with the return value, you need to echo it:

```
img_block($img_name);
```

should be:

```
echo img_block($img_name);
```

Finally you have not put the required `$` on the `img_src` variable in your function; it's definition should be:

```
function img_block($img_src) {
    // e.g. img_src = cat.jpg;
    $img_input = "images/" . $img_src;
    $set_img = '<img class="media-object-ph" src="'.$img_input.'" width="380" height="290" alt="...">';
    return $set_img;
}
```

If you make all these changes, and (e.g.) `$row['img_name'] = 'image1.jpg'`, your code will output:

```
<img class="media-object-ph" src="images/image1.jpg" width="380" height="290" alt="...">
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/3Bgkm)